# My strcat doesn't return a value?

Tags: string, function, char, strcat

I coded a strcat function. But my function doesn't run in this way -----> char * mystrcat(char *s,char *t). I want to return a pointer. Can you help me?

```
#include <stdio.h>

void mystrcat(char *s,char *t)
{
    while(*s!='\0')
        s++;
        s--;
    while((*(s+1)=*t)!='\0')
    {   s++;
        t++;
    }
}

int main()
{

    char str[30], str1[30];
   gets(str);
   gets(str1);
   mystrcat(str, str1);
    printf("%s\n",str);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your function has no **return** value. If you want to return a pointer from it then just return it. And also **void** is incorrect for  that

Comment: when I write return instead void, it doesn't run

Answer (score 0):

When you write `void mystrcat(char *s,char *t)` you are saying "I will not have a return value" by using void. If you want to return a pointer, this must not be `void`.

To return a pointer to your string, use `char**`.

Your string, a series of characters, is represented as a `char*`.

Here's an example using your code.

```
#include <stdio.h>

char** mystrcat(char *s,char *t)
{
    char *sOrig = s;
    while(*s!='\0'){
        s++;
    }
    s--;

    while( ( *(s+1) = *t) != '\0')
    {
        s++;
        t++;
    }
    return &sOrig;
}

int main()
{
   char str[30], str1[30];
   gets(str);
   gets(str1);
   char** concatValuePointer = mystrcat(str, str1);
   printf("Pointer is %p\n",concatValuePointer);
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: The issue, and the basis for this approach, is that you are corrupting the original pointer location that you pass in. By retaining that value (sOrig) prior to incrementing it (s++), you are keeping a reference (i.e. a pointer) to the original pointer. Does this answer your question? If not, please describe further what you would like to accomplish.